# Why is ruby REGEX \A...\z allowing for anything to be entered at beginning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

This Ruby REGEX is allowing +& signs at the beginning, and I have no idea why.

```
 REGEX = /\A0(\d{4,14})|((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))\z/
```

It seems to resolve the issue when I make the parts between A...\z their own group, but it makes me concerned, and would appreciate an explanation from a more experienced individual.

```
 REGEX = /\A(0(\d{4,14})|((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4})))\z/
```

Some other things to note, I'm using this as a validation for a form field within a rails project. The REGEX is being stored as a constant and being compared to the input with the validates: ... {with: REGEX} function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be due to you not including `\A` in your second alternative.

`&` or `+` or any other character in that matter will match at the beginning of your string - if the remaining portion of the regex matches `((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))\z`

Let's assume the separator didn't exist, and let's just look at the 2nd alternative:

```
((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))\z
```

You are not asserting any *beginning of string* requirements (notice: the `\A` doesn't exist in this alternative - as well as the `\z` doesn't exist in your first alternative.)

So, try either one of these, it should work for you.

```
/\A0(\d{4,14})\z|\A0((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))\z/
```

or

```
/\A0(?:(\d{4,14})|((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4})))\z/
```

An online [regex debugger](//regex101.com) can help you debug your pattern. [Take a look](https://regex101.com/r/TxzBLq/2/) at your two alternatives here:

[image]

Notice the blue (handsomely drawn) circle is not showing your `\z` - as well as the red circle not showing the `\A0`?

And a *slightly shortened / optimized* pattern:

```
/\A0(?:\d{4,14}|(?:\d{1,4}-){2}\d{3,4})\z/
```

---

I am slightly confused on why you have two capturing groups that capture the exact same string. `((\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))`. You should probably drop one of them as it appears redundant.

Comment: Thank you. I see now. As for the double grouping, it was likely due to the original being something more like  \A(0\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4})\z then changing that to \A(0\(d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))\z, then finally adding the or and pulling the 0 out.

Comment: I thought that was the intention - but it usually doesn't end well *making assumptions* on SO sometimes :D

Comment: By the way, would grouping everything within the \A...\z be a valid solution?
like so : /\A(0(\d{4,14})|(\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}-\d{3,4}))\z/

Comment: if the `0` is a requirement in **ALL** alternatives, then you can use: `\A0(...|...)\z`. If it's only a requirement in the **First** alt, then you can use `\A(0...|...)\z`.

Comment: The 0 is required for all in this case. So it should be good. Again, thank you so much!